# How to programmatically copy AWS resources from one AWS account to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I built a serverless app on an AWS account (S3, API Gateway, Lambda, DynamoDB, IAM). I need to deploy this on another AWS account that is part of the same AWS organization. Is there a CLI/CloudFormer solution where I can select existing AWS resources and replicate them on different AWS account.

Comment: What are you looking exactly for? You've already mentioned the `CloudFormer` and unfortunatelly it's best you can get creating the CloudFormation templates (some data you will have to define as parameters and some resources need to be defined manually). Still - what do you mean by "AWS resources"? (replicating EBS or stored data is different)

Comment: I am looking to replicate application code and setup. So S3, API gateway, lambda functions, DynamoDB table schemas, IAM roles. Data from the dynamodb tables is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CloudFormation stacks sets: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacksets-concepts.html But the resources need to be maintained by CloudFormation also in first account.